# Using external file jquery for the same time triggering

Tags: jquery

I got the problem for triggering variable, with jquery with the same module and separated.
The scripting like these below:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#but1').click(function(){
var dat1=$('#name').val();
alert(dat1);
});
});

</script>

<body>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<button id="but1">Process</button>
</body>
```

With the same module I can got variable with the same time,if I pressed the button.
But the problem appeared when the script of jquery separated with external file (.js),because I must refresh the page for getting The newest varible value if pressed the button.
This script below for external file js:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="testjava.js"></script>
```

this for testjava.js:

```
$(function(){

var dat1=$('#nama').val();

$('#but1').live('click',function(){

alert(dat1);

});

});
```

Pls show me the way so the variable can be fired in the same time (without refresh page) if I press button with external js? many thx.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code you are kind of explaining yourself but seems english barrier.

Try this as I'm guessing you don't want the click behavior to refresh the page.

```
$('#but1').live('click',function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    alert(dat1);
});
```

Comment: Sorry about my english.But script behavior was not as you mentioned above.I just wanna get output with 2 methods.1st with the script in same page and 2nd with external js.I meant I wanna the same result and same output with the same script but 2 method different methods.thx

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the live() method is going to be deprecated soon and should be avoided.
http://api.jquery.com/live/

Anyway, any code in an inline script element can be placed in an external file and loaded as if it were inline. So change the external file to match the inline code, which works.

So change testjava.js to contain:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#but1').click(function(){
        var dat1=$('#name').val();
        alert(dat1);
    });
});
```

Comment: I already changed script to this above, but still must refresh page for getting newest variable.Am I missing something?.thx

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the button until the script has been loaded.

```
<style type="text/css">
#but1 { display: none; }
</style>
```

testjava.js

```
$(function(){
    $('#but1')
        .show()
        .live('click',function(){
            alert($('#name').val());
        });
});
```

Comment: Yes,I already change the same method above.Frankly I am beginner in jquery.But I just wanna try 2 methods jquery usage.1'st with inline script,2nd with external file with the same script and wanna get the same result.But when I used script with external file, I must refresh page for getting the newest value of variable.